# com.apple.eawt.Application "access restriction"

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm writing a Java app and am currently working on all of the Apple native LAF stuff.  I'm trying to customize the application menu and I've found that I need to use com.apple.eawt.Application in order to do so.  However, when I try to import that class, my IDE says:

```
Access restriction: The type Application is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

I'm using **JDK 1.7** update 45, on **Mac OS X 10.9**, using **Eclipse**.  The **rt.jar** is on the classpath, but something is unhappy.  How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might be trying it with JRE in your build path, you can try changing it to JDK

please refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20197999/2381006)